# Flask: user can access other user session

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I have built a small website with Flask, Flask-login and FLask-sqlalchemy with user login.

When in production:

- if a user A logs himself, he will see his data and views and everything is working ok.
- **Then if a user B just connects to the website from another device at the same time, he will also see the session (and the data) of user A**.

To be noted that I have the same behavior with two different servers: pythonanywhere and O2switch. So, the problem should be on my side :/ (or the 2 servers have a wrong configurations ?)

In local, I have no issue (it is difficult to have the same conditions as in production with another device but let say that I have no issue when using Incognito mode of my browser as the second user).

The code I am using:

`__init__.py`

```py
# library
from flask import Flask
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

# modules
from mywebsite_flask.config import config_selection


# init extensions
db = SQLAlchemy()
login_manager = LoginManager()


# app set-up
def create_app(config_mode):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_selection[config_mode])

    # flask-login init
    login_manager.login_view = "auth_bp.login"
    login_manager.init_app(app)

    # database init
    db.init_app(app)
    from mywebsite_flask.auth.models import Customer
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()

    # add blueprints
    from mywebsite_flask.public.routes import public_bp
    app.register_blueprint(public_bp)
    from mywebsite_flask.auth.routes import auth_bp
    app.register_blueprint(auth_bp)

    app.app_context().push()

    return app
```

`models.py`

```py
# library
from flask_login import UserMixin

# modules
from mywebsite_flask import db, login_manager


class Customer(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    email = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String)
    token_verification = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Customer #{self.id}:{self.email}>"


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(customer_id):  # customer found by unique id
    return Customer.query.get(int(customer_id))
```

`auth.routes.py`

```py
# library
from flask import Blueprint, flash, redirect, render_template, request, url_for
from flask_login import current_user, login_required, login_user, logout_user
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash

# modules
from mywebsite_flask import db
from mywebsite_flask.auth.models import Customer


# init
auth_bp = Blueprint("auth_bp", __name__)


@auth_bp.route("/login", methods=("GET", "POST"))
def login():
    if not current_user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == "POST":
            email = request.form.get("email").lower()
            password = request.form.get("password")
            remember = True if request.form.get("remember") else False

            check_user = db.session.execute(
                db.select(Customer).filter_by(email=email)
            ).scalar_one_or_none()

            if not various_check(check_user):
                # check that none of them are None
                error_msg = "Un des champs requis est vide."
                flash(error_msg, category="error")
            else:
                login_user(check_user, remember=remember)
                return redirect(url_for("public_bp.home"))

        return render_template("auth/login.html")

    else:
        return redirect(url_for("core_bp.customer_home"))


@auth_bp.route("/logout", methods=("GET", "POST"))
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for("public_bp.home"))


# end
```

I have reviewed my code several times, looked at flask-login documentation and read some similar stackoverflow posts without being able to find a solution. Can someone already have the issue or see a problem with my code ?

**Edit**

As requested, a cookie:
[image]

Please note that, when the problem is triggered: if user B connects after user A login, we see the session of user A but there is no cookie present on user B side (and still, we can see and use user A session).

Comment: It's unclear. Do a preliminary debugging and post a [mre] with debugging details. I suspect you are misinterpreting the test result. Did you check cookies stored on each browser?

Comment: Yes it was unclear, a part of explanation was missing. I have added more info. Thanks

Comment: It's still unclear because you didn't post a [mre] with debugging details. Why not test again and check cookies stored in browsers? For example, see [this](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/application/cookies/?utm_source=devtools) for Chrome. Also see [this](https://www.kirsle.net/wizards/flask-session.cgi) for decrypting cookies.

Comment: From a cookie standpoint, everything seems ok. For the minimal code example, How can I procede ? Because the problem appears only when the flask app is hosted on pythonanywhere and not in local

Comment: Post cookies of the browsers.

Comment: Done. I have edited the post

Comment: You should decode and check cookies for each of two browsers. The decoder I linked before does not work anymore. Try [this decoder](https://pypi.org/project/flask-cookie-decode/#cli-that-ships-with-package-which-only-decodes). Also when you post the cookies, don't post a screenshot. Copy and paste all the base64 encoded string. If the cookies contain sensitive information, mask the decoded cookies and post them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have found the problem. 
In the app factory create_app() in *init*.py, I had `app.app_context().push()`

I have added it as a shortcut at the beginning of the project. It was to easily access app.config parameters everywhere in the application.

The problem was solved by:

- removing this `app.app_context().push()`
- using `current_app` (if possible) or `with app.app_context()` (if not), to access app.config (my original need)

`app.app_context().push()` somehow interferes with the different sessions created on server (and more specifically on the `current_user` from flask login)

(thanks @relent95 for your help)